# Download file on Shiny.onInputChange

Tags: javascript, r, download, shiny

I am implementing a download link with `Shiny.onInputChange` which will send a message from client to server. The server will use the message to generate a new file, then provide to user to download. `downloadHandler` can create a button to download a file from server, but cannot receive message from client.

The `Shiny.onInputChange` can be captured by `observeEvent`.

My questtion is how to implement the download feature in the `observeEvent`.

There are some example codes for `Shiny.onInputChange` below. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        HTML('<a href="#" onclick=\'Shiny.onInputChange("i_download", [1,Math.random()]);\'>Download</a>')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$i_download, {
       rep(input$i_download[1])
       # codes to generate a new file and download it
   })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: And, what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can receive the message using `downloadHandler`. Dose this meet your request:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink('down', onclick='Shiny.onInputChange("i_download", [1,Math.random()]);')
  # for shiny 0.14.2 or lower use this instead:
  # tagAppendAttributes(downloadLink('down'),  onclick='Shiny.onInputChange("i_download", [1,Math.random()]);')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$down <- downloadHandler(

    filename = 'down.txt',

    content = function(file) {

      # use the message (input$i_download) to generate a new file

      writeLines(as.character(input$i_download), file)

    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: like this it cant be reproduced, since it leads to: `unused argument (onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange(\"i_download\", [1,Math.random()]);")`.

Comment: @BigDataScientist I'm using shiny 1.0.0. It added a `...` argument to `downloadLink()` and `downloadButton`

Comment: oh, i wasnt up to date on the package. i was aware on the onclick argument just didnt know it for the downloadLink. Thanks a lot @Yang!